# How to pass multiple input through a Keras model with different shapes

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a Keras model with multiple inputs.

```
input_img = Input(shape=(728,))
input_1 = Input(shape=(1,))
input_2 = Input(shape=(1,))

x = (Dense(48,kernel_initializer='normal',activation="relu"))(input_img)
x = (Dropout(0.2))(x)
x = (Dense(24,activation="tanh"))(x)
x = (Dropout(0.3))(x)
x = (Dense(1))(x)
x = keras.layers.concatenate([x, input_1, input_2])
x = (Activation("sigmoid"))(x)
cnn = Model(inputs = ([input_img, input_1, input_2]), outputs = x)
cnn.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer='adam')
```

I defined the inputs as

```
inputs = ([X_train.reshape(10000,728), input_1.reshape(10000,), input_2.reshape(10000,)])
```

and trained as follow

history = cnn.fit(inputs, labels, validation_split = 0.2, epochs=30, batch_size=100, validation_data=(validation, labels_test))

Whenever I run this, I get the following error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_12 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

How do I pass the inputs as shape (3,) if they have different dimensions?

Comment: I never used this, but according to the error, I would say the problem is that you have the 3 arrays inside of a list `[]` being itself inside a tuple `()`, try to remove either the `()` or the `[]` like `inputs = (X_train.reshape(10000,728), input_1.reshape(10000,), input_2.reshape(10000,))`

Comment: This fixes this certain issue by a new issues arises `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'`

Comment: `ndim` is an attribute of numpy arrays so probably the parameter `inputs` should be an `array` and not a `tuple` nor a `list`. Once again, I never used it, but you could try `inputs = np.array([X_train.reshape(10000,728), input_1.reshape(10000,), input_2.reshape(10000,)])` at least it would be an array of shape (3,)

Comment: I am sorry to bother again but there is another error that arises `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10000,728) into shape (10000)` when attempting to transform the list into numpy arrays.

Comment: I would be better to edit the question (or create a new one) with this problem and the full error traceback, and also your import statement to help fix your problem :) it is hard to fix within comments

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code for simulation and seems to be running correctly.

Here is the code for simulation:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Input, Concatenate
import tensorflow as tf

# inputs = ([X_train.reshape(10000,728), input_1.reshape(10000,), input_2.reshape(10000,)])
inputs = ([tf.ones((10000,728)), tf.ones((10000,)), tf.ones((10000,))]) # Input Simulation
labels = tf.ones((10000,3))  # Output Simulation


input_img = Input(shape=(728,))
input_1 = Input(shape=(1,))
input_2 = Input(shape=(1,))

x = (Dense(48,kernel_initializer='normal',activation="relu"))(input_img)
x = (Dropout(0.2))(x)
x = (Dense(24,activation="tanh"))(x)
x = (Dropout(0.3))(x)
x = (Dense(1))(x)
x = keras.layers.concatenate([x, input_1, input_2])
x = (Activation("sigmoid"))(x)
cnn = Model(inputs = ([input_img, input_1, input_2]), outputs = x)
cnn.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer='adam')

cnn.summary()

history = cnn.fit(inputs, labels,  epochs=5, batch_size=100)
```

I would advise you to **check properly your Training Data** and **Label Data shapes** to ensure there are no conflicting shapes that may **raise errors**.
You could also convert your data into **Tensors** and see if this fixes your problem.